# SNS multiple subscribers

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

We have an SNS queue with multiple subscribers (2 * SQS, 1 * email, etc.). However, we only get the notification for the last subscriber.
I.e. when each of them is registered alone we get to notification. So as far as I understand each of them alone is configured all right.

I didn't find any relevant AWS documentation about it (limit of subscribers, policies, etc.)

Would love to hear any hint about it. Thanks in advance.

**Solution:** the issue was the order in which the SQS permission-subscription was created in. The correct order is detailed [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html). If you do step 3 before 2 it won't work.

Comment: Glad you found an answer! Please move the solution to the Answer section and mark it as solved so that other people can find the solution too.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the order in which the SQS permission-subscription was created in. The correct order is detailed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html). If you do step 3 before 2 it won't work.

Comment: This was totally my problem as well - however the correct answer did help.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:<account-number>:<sqs-name>/SQSDefaultPolicy",
  "Statement": [
         {
        "Sid": "<sid>",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:<account-number>:<name>",
        "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                      "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:<account-number>:*"
                     }
                }
          }
     ]
}
```

Here * is the key. It allows other sns to write to the same queue.