# AWS SQS subscription to AWS SNS topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, publish-subscribe, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have use case in that I want to subscribe single SQS to two SNS topic. So that whatever message publish to any SNS should be available in SQS. So my question is Can we subscribe one sqs to two SNS topic?

Any help here will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please also suggest how we can achieve this via terraform?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is possible.

A single SQS can subscribe to multiple SNS Topics

Comment: Thanks Arafat for your quick reply. Could you please suggest how we can achieve this via terraform?

Comment: Not much idea with terraform, but why do you want to use that when there is AWS Cloudformation available

Comment: Services we are using in our project are not from AWS only we are using other cloud services as well. And also for future purpose don't want to stick with AWS.

Comment: @surajchopade, SQS and SNS are part of AWS, so that last comment doesn't quite make sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:<account-number>:<sqs-name>/SQSDefaultPolicy",
"Statement": [
     {
    "Sid": "<sid>",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:<account-number>:<name>",
    "Condition": {
            "ArnEquals": {
                  "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:<account-number>:*"
                 }
            }
  }
 ]
}
```

Here * is the key. It allows other sns to write to the same queue.

I have answered the same here [SNS multiple subscribers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244881/sns-multiple-subscribers/47677861#47677861)